# Install CiviCRM Buildkit on windows xampp

Tags: drupal, civicrm-buildkit, install, windows

how to install buildkit cvcrm on windows?
I've set up xampp, drupal 7.x and civicrm 5.2.x

i just have no clue what to do with the buildkit zip file which I've downloaded from here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit

please advice

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't, I'm afraid. It doesn't work on Windows.

From https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/ :

[image]