# How to install civiCRM buidkit in WAMP server localhost with Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, civicrm-buildkit, windows

I am new to civiCRM. I would like to install CiviCRM buildkit on my local environment. I am using WAMP server. I have followed this link: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/ but cannot find any useful notes for Windows installation.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install CiviCRM Buildkit on windows xampp](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25633/install-civicrm-buildkit-on-windows-xampp)

Comment: I want to use in WAMP.

Comment: As the answer there says, you can't use it on windows.

Comment: To my knowledge, the only way to set up a local dev environment on Windows is to install Linux inside windows, which is complex. It might be worth for you to dual boot and install linux into a partition. Just an idea, good luck.